# Reload Highchart with AJAX more smoothly

Tags: highcharts

you can see my test example of Highchart here: [Chart test](http://24fudbal.com.mk/chart-test.php)

When you click the "Reload chart" button, it reloads the chart with random numbers. But as you can see, the chart disappears for a very short time and reappears again. My question is: can I reload the chart more smoothly, without it disappearing for a very short time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using Chrome on OS X, it doesn't hiccup at all--the old chart is immediately replaced with a new one which then takes some time to animate into full view.  So if it's the animation time  you object to, I suggest simply setting the animate property of the chart to false to avoid that.

If that's still not good enough (e.g. other browsers might be slower), you can first turn off animation then use the Highcharts API to adjust the data and redraw the chart without recreating it at all.  This may be more invasive, however, so it's worth starting with the first approach.

Comment: Thank you, I think turning off the animation will be enough.